# Getting a type error in my program (beginner at python)

Tags: python, string, formatting, command-line-arguments

I'm attempting to write a program that repeatedly reads inputs to the command line using a while loop. I want to skip the even numbers and print only the odd numbers. Inputs are always valid.

Here's what I've got:

```
    import sys

    num = sys.argv

    while True:
      for x in num:
        if x % 2 == 0:
           continue
      else: 
        print(x)
```

I get this error: "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv` contains strings, not numbers. You can use the `int()` function to convert strings to numbers.

But you should skip the first element of `sys.argv`, because it contains the name of the script, which is unlikely to be a number.

There's no need for the `continue` statement. Just reverse the sense of the test and print the value there.

```
import sys

num = sys.argv[1:]

for x in num:
    if int(x) % 2 == 1:
        print(x)
```

The equivalent `while` loop is:

```
i = 1
while i < len(sys.argv):
    if int(sys.argv[i]) % 2 == 1:
        print(sys.argv[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: This worked great, but I need to do it with a while loop.

Comment: OK I added the while loop. That will just keep printing the same results forever.

Comment: I appreciate the help! I'll kick it around until I figure out how to stop the loop after it prints out the odd inputs once.

Comment: Why do yuo need the while loop? If you get rid of it you'll print the odd inputs just once.

Comment: If this is an assignment, maybe you're supposed to use a `while` loop *instead* of the `for` loop, not use both of them. You should explain all the requirements in the question.

Comment: That was the challenge, to do it within a while loop. The for loop is not part of it, I could get rid of that.

Comment: Maybe something like `i = 1 while i < len(sys.argv): ...`

Comment: But that seems to be unrelated to the type error, which is what your question is about.

Comment: I added a for loop because you can't perform operations with a list. So I iterated over "num" with x to take the modulus of each number in it.

Comment: You can use `sys.argv[i]` in the while loop.

Comment: I see it but that loop is still going to run forever

Comment: Oops, forgot to increment i

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a while True if using sys.argv, and your else is indented wrong. 
    import sys

```
num = sys.argv


for x in num:
    if int(x) % 2 != 0:
        print(x)
```

Or if you want it to run continuously as you seem to say try:

```
while True:
    x = input("Number: ")
    if int(x) % 2 != 0:
        print(x)
```

Comment: Your solution is great too, but I can't use inputs for this. Sys.argv only